# Do inertia affect stiffness matrix of beam?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, elasticity, structural-beam

Refering to a pdf I uploaded at [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D1grhv6TISmHuadX98WORu5Egu0jszES/view?usp=sharing). Why does these stiffness matrix displacement do not need to consider the inertia (determines the shape of cross-sectional area of each element) ? I have always thought that the inertia will affect the displacement too. Thank you for reading and have a nice day :)

[image]
[image]

Comment: You mean $I$ as in [second moment of area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_moment_of_area), and _not_ mass moment of inertia.

Comment: @JAlex, yes sorry. Its the moment of inertia that affects the amount of displacement. However, why does the stiffness matrix does not have that? Does that mean any shape of cross-sectional area will produce the same amount of defection caused by the same load in stiffness matrix?

Comment: Stiffness matrix **is** dependent on $I$ if bending is involved. The link to personal drives is blocked in many cases. Please consider embedding images as needed, and type the equations out using math formatting [MathJAX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @JAlex, but wouldnt applying load will cause bending haha?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello! It is [preferable](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/) to type out screenshots or images of text; for formulae, one can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed the stiffness matrix **for problems with bending** is dependent on the [area moment](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/area-moment-inertia-d_1328.html) $I$ as well as the elastic modulus $E$_.

Take the example of a cantilever beam.

Page 2 of [this pdf lecture](http://www.ce.memphis.edu/7117/notes/presentations/chapter_04b.pdf) for example, shows the following

[image: fig1]

As you can see the stiffness matrix depends on $E I$ (shown outside the matrix as a common factor) where $E$ is the modulus of elasticity and $I$ is are second moment of area of the beam.

<sub>For example a rectangular beam has $ I = b h^3/12$.</sub>

But for problems with **only axial deflection** (like the truss made of rods the question describes), then the stiffness matrix only depends on the axial stiffness of the rod which is $ k = \frac{E A}{L}$

Comment: Hi, I have updated a picture above. It does not involve any inertia at all

Comment: This pdf is a force on a truss system analysis which involves tension and compression. But, tension and compression is caused by bending

Comment: @catherinetan - The truss members are two-force members that carry **only** axial load, and no side loading / moment. So each member can only compress or expand _and cannot bend_. This is what $I$ is not involved here.

Comment: Hi Alex, so you are saying the final  total  displacement of truss caused by the dispalcement of  (tension compression ) of truss member and the displacement caused by bending moment of the entire truss structure (if we consider the moment of inertia of the entire truss structure ? :)

Comment: @catherinetan - yes, the deformed shape is due to individual member tensions/compression. You might describe the overall deflection as "bending" only when the structure approximates a beam in shape. But a structure made of rods in the shape of a sphere for  example won't "bend".

Comment: Alex, hmmm, why structure made of rods in the shape of a sphere for example won't "bend" ?

Comment: @catherinetan - it would squish. I treat bending as deflection in a direction perpendicular to the dominant dimension of the shape.

Comment: Hi Alex, I posted a new question at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/704964/truss-deflection-problem

Comment: It includes bending but delection does not even depend on shape?